# Using the taskscheduleR package in R Studio to fetch data and keep it updated into a CSV file

Tags: r

I'm using the taskscheduleR package in R Studio to fetch data and keep it updated into a CSV file:

This is my code. It works when sourced manually:

```
library(tidycovid19)
covid19_dta <- download_merged_data(silent = TRUE, cached = TRUE)
filename <- file.path("D:\\OneDrive\\Portal Gestão\\Projetos - Documentos\\Covid19\\TaskScheduler",
                      "covid19.csv")
write.csv(covid19_dta, file = filename, row.names = FALSE)
```

But when running from the scheduler, I get the error:

```
 Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: write.csv -> eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> write.table -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'D:\OneDrive\Portal Gestão\Projetos - Documentos\Covid19\TaskScheduler/covid19.csv': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

I've tried this other similar post, escaping the path, and a lot of other stuff, but can't get this running.

Comment: Is the file being used by some other process? If you have it open in e.g. Excel you'll get that `cannot open the connection` error

Comment: I actually delete the csv file prior to running the task to check if it is created (it's not).